# Node child process cleanup

Tags: node.js, child-process

Node processes started with `require('child_process').spawn` can `close` and `exit`.  I assume they can also just hang forever in some cases without politely telling Node about it.  How do I make sure my Node application always cleans up its child processes nicely?  I know that `kill` can be used to "Send a signal to the child process".  This doesn't sound like much of a guarantee, especially since the docs say "Note that while the function is called kill, the signal delivered to the child process may not actually kill it. kill really just sends a signal to a process."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly how **kill** works on linux. The node counterpart provides the same functionality.

`kill` sends SIGTERM signal by default. Force kill via `kill -9` sends SIGKILL. SIGKILL cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored. But use this as last resort. It prevents the process to clean up lockfiles.

See the linux documentation for [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) and the [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) used.

Comment: Interesting.  How would you suggest I clean up the processes then?  I assume try the default sigterm kill, then check back later and send a sigkill if the process is still alive?  How long should I wait before sending the sigkill?

Comment: SIGTERM may be ignored by process and it can keep on running indefinitely. That is when you need SIGKILL. It depends on your needs. If you are spawning light processes frequently then keep timeout small 1-2 secs. But if you started a heavyweight process/daemon you should make it more to ensure safe exit like database server. But from my experience you should not need SIGKILL. More importantly if you need it, that indicates problem with program itself.

Comment: Thanks man.  This is useful information.  I'm guessing Node's Windows version has issues with this level of subtlety, but I'll probably be hosting on a linux box anyway.